Move an existing software RAID 1 from one PC to another
I have PC with W10 installed on a separate disk and 2 other hard disks configured as software RAID 1(disks mirrored).
I need to move the two hard disks configured as software RAID 1 to another Windows 10 PC.
Is that possible?
Do I have to rebuild the RAID 1 from scratch on the new PC?
How do I migrate the RAID 1 without losing data from that array of disks?
Many thanks for your suggestions

Can you explain with more clarity what you mean by "migrate"? Do you hope to physically transfer the disks in question from one PC to another? Or are you planning to share them somehow, or what? Also, what software is configuring the RAID? The hardware details of the source and destination computer are likely also very relevant, so please include those. Finally, if you are planning to move the disks the short answer is probably: Backup the data, move the disks, (re)create the RAID, restore the data.

Thanks for looking on this thread and providing help ! By migrate I mean to remove 2 disks from one PC and install them on another windows 10 PC. The two disks are already mirrored in the previous windows 10 PC, so I need to know what steps I should follow up to have the same RAID 1 . Create a RAID 1 from scratch should clear data on disks I think,so it looks that I have to backup the data first and later create the  RAID1 and restore the data from backup. It looks a long process and maybe there would be another short path. Thanks !

To begin with: all that info needs to be in the main question. Your goal right now is to make your main question as clear and complete as possible. It should not be necessary to wade through comments to understand what you're asking, so make sure all the good and juicy details are there in the main question.
